# How to create resolution-sensitive web pages that adapt themselves automatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, visual-studio, css, dreamweaver

Two example are ASP.NET MVC Internet Application template and the functionality that manages different presentations across various screen resolution in Dreamweaver. If I want to implement myself, what should I do? Actually, I need to cut out some auto adaption shipped with the MVC template because it kind of messes my UI up but I don't know where the key part is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into css media queries.

You can do stuff like:

```
 @media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px),
    /* Target only screen with resolutions between 520px to  699px;*/
    }
```